# mint_to instruction is failing ,`Program logged: "Error: InvalidAccountData"`with this error

Tags: anchor, solana-program, spl-token-program

I'm using this code to mint

```
let cpi_accounts = MintTo {
            mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.ata.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.owner.to_account_info(),
        };
        let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();

        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);

        token::mint_to(cpi_ctx, 1)?;
```

and i'm getting this log

```
Program invoked: Token Program
  > Program logged: "Instruction: MintTo"
  > Program logged: "Error: InvalidAccountData"
  > Program consumed: 1261 of 190597 compute units
  > Program returned error: "invalid account data for instruction"
> Program consumed: 10664 of 200000 compute units
```

previously it was working, but it suddenly stopped working

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the appropriate token account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InvalidAccountData` can unfortunately mean many things, but most likely the mint account hasn't been created / initialized, or the token account hasn't been created / initialized.